# Send slack message with result from Powershell

Tags: powershell, slack-api

I am trying to send slack message by powershell and I got stuck. here is my script. Looks like I can't use $result for -text.

What I am trying to do is to send an alert to slack channel if there is any free disk space lower than 15% or 10%.

I am using PSSlack from Powershell Gallery.

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Continue"; 
$percentCritcal = 15;

$computers = Get-Content "D:\Disk_Usage\ServerList.txt"
$result = foreach($computer in $computers) 
{ 
    $disks = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $computer -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter "DriveType = 3" 
    $computer = $computer.ToUpper() 
    foreach($disk in $disks) 
    {         
        $Size = $disk.Size
        $Freespace = $disk.FreeSpace
        $sizeGB = [Math]::Round($Size / 1073741824, 2)
        $freeSpaceGB = [Math]::Round($Freespace / 1073741824, 2)
        $percentFree = [Math]::Round(($freespace / $size) * 100, 2);

        $ResultHash = [ordered]@{
            Computer = $computer
            Drive = $disk.DeviceID
            SizeGB = $sizeGB
            UsedGB = $sizeGB - $freeSpaceGB
            FreeGB = $freeSpaceGB
            PercFree = $percentFree  
        } 

        New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $ResultHash
    }  
}

$Result = $Result | Where-Object {$_.PercFree -lt 10}

if ($Result) 
{
    $token = 'xxxxxxxxxxx'
    $Result = $Result | Format-Table | Out-String

    New-SlackMessageAttachment -Color $_PSSlackColorMap.red `
                               -Title 'Disk Free Space Alert' `
                               -Text $result  `
                               -Fallback 'Bad boy' |

    New-SlackMessage -Channel '#it-test' `
                     -IconEmoji :bomo: `
                     -AsUser `
                     -Username 'BOT' |

    Send-SlackMessage -Token $token  
}
```

The result is like this, it is repeating the same drive for couple times[image]

Any idea?

Comment: What's $result ? You are not emitting anything out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with your code is that `$Result` never gets populated with anything. The simplest fix would be to create an object in the ForEach loop, which will then populate $Result.

For example:

```
$result = foreach($computer in $computers) 
{ 
    $disks = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $computer -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter "DriveType = 3" 
    $computer = $computer.ToUpper() 
    foreach($disk in $disks) 
    {         
        $Size = $disk.Size
        $Freespace = $disk.FreeSpace
        $sizeGB = [Math]::Round($Size / 1073741824, 2)
        $freeSpaceGB = [Math]::Round($Freespace / 1073741824, 2)

        $ResultHash = [ordered]@{
            Computer = $computer
            deviceID = $disk.DeviceID
            volName = $disk.VolumeName 
            percentFree = [Math]::Round(($Freespace / $Size) * 100, 2) 
            sizeGB = $sizeGB
            freeSpaceGB = $freeSpaceGB
            usedSpaceGB = $sizeGB - $freeSpaceGB
        }

        New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $ResultHash
    }  
}
```

**Explanation:**

The above code has taken your existing variables and turned them in to properties of a hash table `@{ }`. This hash table is then used to create the properties of an object with `New-Object`.

Because New-Object is on a line on it's own, it's result goes in to the pipeline, which is ultimately output to $Result because that's where you send the result of the `ForEach`.

`[ordered]` in front of the Hashtable should keep the properties in the order that they've been defined. Note that this requires PowerShell v3 or above.

---

Depending on how you want it to look, you might want to also do this to $Result after the `ForEach` and before you use it in the Slack Message:

````
$Result = '```' + ($Result | Format-Table | Out-String) + '```'
````

This should make the message formatted as fixed width code in a tabular format. Of course you might want to modify the output differently, just a suggestion.

Comment: I updated the answer a couple of times. Are you using my code exactly as above? (Including new-object). Can you share your full revised code in a gist or pastebin maybe.

Comment: Script updated with your latest version. after sending to Slack, now it shows as "System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary"

Comment: Don't use $resulthash, use $result in your slack message. Also see my note above about how you might want to reformat $result for slack first.

Comment: What if I dont use any table, just send PC name and %of free space as text?

Comment: $result | select computer,percentfree

Comment: I tried with just $result, error "New-SlackMessageAttachment : Cannot process argument transformation on 
parameter 'Text'. Cannot convert value to type System.String."

Comment: Do this first: $Result = '```' + ($Result | Format-Table | Out-String) + '```'

Comment: Oh it's lost the back ticks, see that at the end of my answer.

Comment: it is working !!! Only thing is that the column needs more room so it wont become double lines. I can change the column to shorter names

Comment: what if I want to display the only drive that free space is lower thatn 10% instead of displaying all drives on the host? with current code, it shows all local drives on the host. and I want it sends to slack only if there is one or more hosts have lowe space disk. I am using if ($i -gt 0), but it seems not functioning. thx

Comment: $Result = $Result | Where-Object {$_.percentfree -lt 10}

Comment: Do that after the foreach loop but before you send to slack.

Comment: Couldnt make your way to work, i also updated my original code with "if($percentFree -lt $percentCritcal) " and "if ($i -gt 0)" does it make any sense to you?

Comment: I've updated the code in your question with how I suggest you make this work. It filters $Result to just those where the PercFree value is less than 10 and then only attempts to send a message to Slack if $Result has any value (e.g if there are no disks less than 10 perc free then it doesn't try to message Slack). Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help again. It works now only showing the drive where less than 10% but it repeat it for couple time. I updated the post with result.

Comment: The problem is this bit: if($percentFree -lt $percentCritcal) { .. } is not necessary. That's stopping the hashtable from being correctly populated for every disk. I'll edit it out.

Comment: Try that. We now gather the data for all disks, then at the end we filter $Result down to just the disks that are less than 10 percent.

Comment: As an aside, it's a bit of an abuse of StackOverflow to continue to ask different questions via an existing question like this via editing. You should instead raise these as new questions (then also anyone in the community will help you). When you've got it working, I will revert your question to it's original one so that my answer still makes sense, and we should both delete off these unnecessary comments (think of it as leaving just what might be useful to someone else in the future).

Comment: Thank you very much for all the help. I will make a different question if i need. Great help